# Field 'id' expected a number but got <>ManyRelatedManager object

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to remove a field in a many to many relationship but I came across this error and I dont know how to solve/fix it.

Here is what I am trying to do:

1: Before the below views I get a valid POST from user identifing `data.log_order`

2: I search if there are previous logs in `ActiveSession`. If there is search for matching logs with the same received `data.log_order` and delete the existing one and add the new received data.

3: If there is no matching `data.log_order` in log or previous logs to add the new received data.

As simple as the logic as difficult as I am struggling to get my errors fixed.

```
class Log(models.Model):
    ...................................
    log_order = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)],blank=True, null=True)

class LogForm(forms.Form):
    .............................
    log_order = forms.IntegerField()

class ActiveSession(models.Model):
    log = models.ManyToManyField(Log, related_name='savedlogs')
    ..................................
```

Here is the views:

```
                if active_session.log.values():
                    print(active_session.log.values())
                    for i in active_session.log.values():
                        if i['log_order']==int(data.log_order):
                            log_order = data.log_order
                            log=Log.objects.filter(log_order=log_order)
                            print(log)
                            active_session = ActiveSession.objects.get(id=ActiveSession.objects.last().id,log__in=log)
                            print(active_session)
                            active_session.log.remove(active_session.log)
                            active_session.log.add(data)
                            print(active_session.log.values())
                        else:
                            active_session.log.add(data)
                            print(active_session.log.values())
                            print('Existing Log with different order_no')
                else:
                    active_session.log.add(data)
                    print('Log added to Session')
                    print(active_session.log.values())
                return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Portfolio\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1774, i
n get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ManyRelatedManager'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Portfolio\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in in
ner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Portfolio\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_r
esponse
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Gym_App\my_gym\views.py", line 115, in addlog
    active_session.log.remove(active_session.log)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Portfolio\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", l
ine 967, in remove
    self._remove_items(self.source_field_name, self.target_field_name, *objs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Portfolio\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", l
ine 1197, in _remove_items
    self.through._default_manager.using(db).filter(filters).delete()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Portfolio\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 942, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Portfolio\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 962, in _filter_o
r_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Portfolio\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 969, in _filter_o
r_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Portfolio\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1360, in add_
q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Portfolio\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1379, in _add
_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Portfolio\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1239, in buil
d_filter
    return self._add_q(
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Portfolio\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1379, in _add
_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Portfolio\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1321, in buil
d_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Portfolio\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1167, in buil
d_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Portfolio\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 24, in __init__

    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Portfolio\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py", line
59, in get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = [target_field.get_prep_value(v) for v in self.rhs]
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Portfolio\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py", line
59, in <listcomp>
    self.rhs = [target_field.get_prep_value(v) for v in self.rhs]
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Portfolio\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1776, i
n get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_t
o_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x04E93418>.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line of code is what is causing the error:

```
active_session.log.remove(active_session.log)
```

As stated in the [remove](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove) documentation:

> For many-to-many relationships remove() accepts either model instances
> or field values, normally primary keys, as the *objs argument.

What you are passing to `remove` is the manager of the many-to-many field rather than one or multiple objects.

I'm not entirely sure which objects you are trying to delete from the m2m field, but if you want to delete them all you should either use:

```
active_session.log.remove(*active_session.log.all())
```

OR

```
active_session.log.clear()
```

OR in general:

```
active_session.log.remove(*logs)
```

**note that the asterix is required and not a spelling error**

If you want to delete only a single object you should pass a `Log` object like this.

```
active_session.log.remove(log)
```

Comment: I am trying to delete only a single object and whenever I pass `active_session.log.remove(log)` I get `Field 'id' expected a number but got <QuerySet[<...>]. I am trying to delete the logs with specific `log_order`

Comment: @A_K, that is because the `log` variable is not a single log but a Queryset of logs: `log=Log.objects.filter(log_order=log_order)`. If you are using this definition for the `log` variable, you should use the following syntax: active_session.log.remove(*log) **note that the asterix is necessary, and not a spelling mistake**